Updated my application, now all updates and new install fails after downloading
I have an app that has been live for 6 months, updated regularly. Yesterday, i pushed an update in production, and all the updates from earlier versions and new installs fail, after downloading, with the error "Can't download App":
Can't download App
This is what's logged after the failed installation:

Marking session 1958194103 as failed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Failed to read manifest from /data/app/vmdl1958194103.tmp/base.apk: For input string: "GAME"

this is my manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.paranoidsquirrels.idleguildmaster">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IdleGuildMaster">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="uiMode">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/game_services_project_id"/>

    </application>

</manifest>

This error happens in internal test, too.
What i tried to solve the problem:

Made an entirely new project on the play console with a different name, where i uploaded in internal test a brand new project that contained the exact same code/assets as the old one, and used the same .jks keystore. It worked.
took this project, changed ONLY the package name to match the one of the main project, uploaded in the main Play Console project's internal test track. Failed with the same error above
tried to update, in internal test track, a different, unrelated older app that never had this problem. Failed with the same error.

Anyone has an idea of what may be happening?

Looking around i found a few similar problems that arised recently, like this one: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION Error when downloading my app from Google Play
However,the solution to locally turn off app optimization in the Play Store did not work for me.
Until a few years ago, there was the possibility of turning it off in Android Studio. The possibility has now been removed.
However, i managed to solve the problem by unckecking a box under Files -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Hot Swap -> Enable hot-swap agent for Groovy code.
